# Searching only specific fields with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

How can I tell Elasticsearch to exclude a field when searching by a term?

I have an index of users (names, email, certifications, experience, office...), but only certain people can search for users by certification. In my current PHP Lucene implementation I have 2 separate indexes with and without that data. Is there a way I can do this with only one users index? I assume I need to apply some kind of filter [[1]](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query.html) [[2]](http://elastica.io/en/search-documents#section-filter), but don't see one that will allow me to ignore a field entirely.

If there is any way specifically to do this with [Elastica (PHP Client)](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica) that would be even more helpful, but native ES would be equally as helpful.

Say I have 2 users in my index

Kevin Smith
Certified in Muffin Making

Mark Smith
Certified in Motorcycle jumping.

When a normal user searched for motorcycle, nothing should be returned, but if they search for Smith both should be returned.

A user with the ability to search the certifications field will return Mark if they search for motorcycle and both if they search for Smith.

Comment: You can control what fields you are querying and which ones you return. What do you mean by ignoring a field? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, the users search index has ~10 fields, so I was hoping to be able to ignore or exclude the one field, while still searching the others. Is my only option to list out the ~9 fields I do want to search just to not search one?

Comment: It's clearer, I'd try clarify the question if I were you. What kind of query are you making?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested anything, but it seems that you might be able to set "include_in_all" to false on the mapping phase. That means that your field won't be include in the "_all". Then you just have to make a query on "_all" fields. 
Note that the field is still available for search and indexed, you can query it by specifying  it in the field query; it's just excluded from the "_all" parameters.

Again I haven't tested anything yet.